# Why cocos2d::RepeatForever in cocos2d::Spawn doesn't work?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

This code works:

```
cocos2d::MoveBy* action = myCreateAction();
cocos2d::Animate* animation = myCreateAnimation();
cocos2d::Spawn* moving = cocos2d::Spawn::createWithTwoActions(action, animation);
runAction(moving);
```

This code works too, but animation is longer than action, therefore action are discontinuous:

```
cocos2d::MoveBy* action = myCreateAction();
cocos2d::Animate* animation = myCreateAnimation();
cocos2d::Spawn* moving = cocos2d::Spawn::createWithTwoActions(action, animation);
runAction(cocos2d::RepeatForever::create(moving));
```

If I run this code:

```
cocos2d::RepeatForever* action = cocos2d::RepeatForever::create(myCreateAction());
cocos2d::RepeatForever* animation = cocos2d::RepeatForever::create(myCreateAnimation());
cocos2d::Spawn* moving = cocos2d::Spawn::createWithTwoActions(action, animation);
runAction(moving);
```

Nothing happens. Why?